# Mapping the Apiary with Restkit

Tags: ios, restkit, apiary.io

I am using rest kit for mapping the response from REST api. When i am try to the response from the `apiary.io`, it is always mapping the response as error. Anyone have done this, please explain how to do this.

For Example :
I made request to the “Apiary.io/login” (just an example url) with two input email and password with the help of RestKit. The response will is received which is mapped as failure.

Input :

```
{ “email” : “test”, “password” : “password” }
```

Output :

```
Response  Code : 201
{ “message” : “success” }
```

But always the failure block is called when a make call post request

```
postObject:(id)object path:(NSString *)path parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success failure:(void (^) (RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure.
```

Comment: Would you be able to share a bit more information about what you are trying, perhaps some example code making the request?

Comment: @kylef can you get it now.

Comment: Could you share your mappings and response descriptors too?

Comment: Are you trying to request http://apiary.io/login or the mock server for your blueprint?

Comment: What is the error provided?

Comment: @Wain  
Please find the error which I received using RestKit
error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (400-499), got 201" UserInfo=0x7f82bac51910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the response descriptor is pointing to the different API actually. I have changed to the API for "login" and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The error `Expected status code in (400-499), got 201` means that you have defined a response descriptor for failure error codes but not success error codes. So, when your request succeeds RestKit interprets it as a failure because you haven't told it to expect a success code and what it should do with it.

Add a new response descriptor which will be used for success HTTP status codes.